# R Shiny application without the use of DT leading to odd issues when displaying DataTables, "requested unknown parameter" warning and odd display bugs

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, dt

I am attempting to build an application but cannot use the R package `DT` and need to rely solely on `data.table` for displaying data. Testing with the iris dataset if I run this line: 
`output$testStats <- renderDataTable(data.table(iris))`
I am prompted with this warning: 
[image]

And after I press okay and scroll to see the data, it appears like this:
[image]

which is incorrectly displayed.

I discovered a bit of a workaround where If I added some Data.Table options, the data would have more success displaying, BUT for whatever reason the added options were also taken in as new columns(??), see below for code and resulting table: 
`output$testStats <- renderDataTable(data.table(iris, rownames = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 10, columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")))))`
[image]

My first thought was maybe this is because the data.table() function had the added options within it, but when I closed the parentheses after `iris`, and then added the options:
`output$testStats <- renderDataTable(data.table(iris), options = list(pageLength = 10, columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"))))` 
It once again gives me the "requested unknown parameter" warning and the table displays like the first screenshot in the post.

The ui call is simply `dataTableOutput("testStats")`.

Is displaying data properly in shiny even doable without `DT`?

This seems like very odd behavior to me and I'm not sure how to work around it. It also seems very odd that no errors/earning appear in my RStudio console. Any help or suggestions here would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem like this is possible since, ````Rstudio```` recommend using `````DT```` over the default data tables in shiny. See ````help(renderDataTable)````. Additionally, ````DT```` processes user queries in the server, which means searches will be done in R rather than in the browser. Whereas for shiny's datatable, this is done in the browser, which can be slow and inefficient. Is there a reason why you can't use ````DT````?

Comment: I don't know whether this is the problem but you don't have to use `data.table`, try with an ordinary dataframe.

Comment: `data.table` in R's package sense is completely separate from rendering data frames/tables in `shiny`, whether with the `DT` package or shiny's native stuff.